# How to expand $\left(1+px+qx^2\right)^{-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$ in the expansion of $\left(1+px+qx^2\right)^{-2}$ in ascending powers of $x$ are 4 and 14 respectively. Find the values of $p$ and $q$.

How should you go about solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general

$$(1+y)^{-2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (k+1) \, y^k$$

so that

$$(1+p x+q x^2)^{-2} = 1 - 2 (p x+q x^2) + 3 (p x + q x^2)^2 - \cdots$$

Out to $O(x^2)$:

$$(1+p x+q x^2)^{-2} = 1 -2 p x + (3 p^2 - 2 q) x^2 + \cdots$$

$$-2 p = 4 \implies p=-2$$

$$3 p^2-2 q=14 \implies -2 q=2 \implies q = -1$$

You can also consider the derivatives of $(1+y)^{-2}$ at $y=0$:

$$\frac{d}{dy} (1+y)^{-2} = -2 (1+y)^{-3}$$
$$\frac12 \frac{d^2}{dy^2} (1+y)^{-2} = 3 (1+y)^{-4}$$

Comment: Can you show how you got from the second to the third line on the RHS please? That is from [1−2(px+qx^2 )+3(px+qx^2 )^2 −⋯]  to [1−2px+(3p^2 −2q)x^2 +⋯]

Comment: @GezBishop: all you need to do is extract the first term from the square term.  This is because you only need to keep the $x$ and $x^2$ terms.  The other terms you get from expanding the square term are coefficients of $x^3$ and $x^4$, which you do not need.